# Date to String in VB.Net MS Access 2013

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I have a field in a table consists of date and String e.g **04Jan_lole**. I want to generate this field in Visual Basic,

> Date + "_" + theName

gives me *mismatch error*, so I try to convert the date part to string:

> StrField = theDate.ToString("ddMMM")

gives me *invalid qualifier error*.

what should I do to generate this format : **04Jan_lole**?
noticing that! If I want to define theDate as DateTime it gives me the error *automation type is not supported by Visual Basic.*

Comment: Where do you see the *"invalid qualifier error"*?  Is it at design-time or run-time?  What line of code causes the error?  What's the full text of the error?  How is `StrField` being declared?  What type is it?

Comment: Oh, wait...  Is this VBA?  I assumed, based the example code and the question's tags that you were writing the code in VB.NET.  If you are trying to run this code in VBA, that would certainly explain why it wouldn't work.  VBA and VB.NET are entirely different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question why it is that you are getting that *invalid qualifier error*.  Perhaps because you are trying to use VB.NET syntax in VBA?  However, if you are actually using VB.NET, the following code should work for you:

```
Public Function FormatDateAndName(theDate As Date, theName As String) As String
    Return theDate.ToString("ddMMMM") & theName
End Function
```

Then, you could call it like this:

```
Dim myDate As New Date(2004, 1, 1)
Dim myName As String = "_lole"
Dim dateAndName As String = FormatDateAndName(myDate, myName)
Console.WriteLine(dateAndName)  ' Outputs "04Jan_lole"
```

In VBA (rather than VB.NET), you should be able to use it like this:

```
Public Function FormatDateAndName(theDate As Date, theName As String) As String
    FormatDateAndName = Format(theDate, "ddMMMM") & theName
End Function
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
Dim result As String
result = FormatDateAndName(#1/1/2004#, "_lole")
MsgBox(result)
```